# How do I call the PHP mail() function in my JS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a dilema. I've created this order request page for a website I'm building, and here's how it works:

1. You check/uncheck core items, and based on it's state (active or unactive), it'll apply a true/false value to a boolean in the coresponding `order.js`. Likewise, it'll take desired unit count for other items, and your information, and apply them to variables.
2. It groups those variables into arrays and, right now, `console.log()` them.

Here's where the trouble comes...this is a snippet of the order.js file.

```
function compileInfo() {

    console.log("compileInfo active");

    var name = "Name: " + $("#name").val() + "\n";
    var email = "Email: " + $("#email").val() + "\n";
    var phone = "Phone: " + $("#phone").val() + "\n";
    var weddingDate = "Wedding Date: " + $("#date").val() + "\n";
    var comments = "Comments: " + $("#comments").val() + "\n";

    var base = "Base Experience: " + $("#base").hasClass("active") + "\n";
    var special = "Special Edition: " + $("#special").hasClass("active") + "\n";
    var teaser = "Teaser Trailer: " + $("#teaser").hasClass("active") + "\n";
    var raw = "Raw Footage: " + $("#raw").hasClass("active") + "\n";

    var standard = "Standard Shipping: " + $("#standard").hasClass("active") + "\n";
    var expedited = "Expedited Shipping: " + $("#expedited").hasClass("active") + "\n";

    var dvd = "Standard DVD: " + a + "\n";
    var br = "Standard Blu-Ray: " + b + "\n";
    var dvdSe = "Special DVD: " + x + "\n";
    var brSe = "Special Blu-Ray: " + y + "\n";

    var info = new Array();
        info[0] = name;
        info[1] = email;
        info[2] = phone;
        info[3] = weddingDate;
        info[4] = comments;

    var services = new Array();
        services[0] = base;
        services[1] = special;
        services[2] = teaser;
        services[3] = raw;

    var delivery = new Array();
        delivery[0] = standard;
        delivery[1] = expedited;

    var extras = new Array();
        extras[0] = dvd;
        extras[1] = br;
        extras[2] = dvdSe;
        extras[3] = brSe;

    var dataVar = info + "\n" + services + "\n" + delivery + "\n" + extras;
    var dataVarJSON = JSON.stringify(dataVar);

    console.log(dataVar);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "order.php",
        data: {data : dataVarJSON},

        success: function() {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        }
    });
}

function validate() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var weddingDate = $("#date").val();

    if (name === "" || email == "" || weddingDate == "") {
        alert("You must complete all required fields to send this request.");
    } else {
        console.log("working");
        compileInfo();
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here's my recieving PHP:

```
<?php
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

    $body = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

    $to = "thekevinhaube@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Order Request";

    function sendInfo() {
        mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }
 ?>
```

Now, I'm far from a PHP expert. This is my first encounter with it, in fact. How can I get it to send. It seems to `POST` just fine, but isn't sending to the email adress listed. Any and all help is appreciated! Again, this is my first time with PHP, so...

Comment: Where do you call `sendInfo`?

Comment: And you probably don't want to use `stripslashes()` on your `POST` variable as that can mess up your json, causing `$body` to become `NULL`. Oh, and you have a variable scope problem in your uncalled function.

Comment: I'm not quire sure how to call the sendInfo function, though I do now realize that's one problem I have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give sendInfo some parameters:

```
function sendInfo($to, $subject, $body) {
  ...
}
```

And don't try mail() on your localhost, try it - if possible - online.

Comment: One problem I have is not knowing how to call the PHP function. Could you further explain that?

Comment: yes, well, when using a function you have to think of it as a separate "thing" in your program. it does not know about whats going on in the rest of your program. so you have to give it something to work with = the parameters. the parameters are the values your function can work with, e.g. `function addValues($value1, $value2) { return $value1+$value2; }`
you can now call it and give it the data it needs: `echo addValues(4, 5);`
will return 9 and display 9. you don't need your function in your project. just type `mail($to, $subject, $body);`